# How to display table column using the ID of another table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, razor

Here are my classes:

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

I want to display in @Html.DisplayFor the CityName which is should be a match in CityID of the Office class.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should create ViewModel name looks likes `OfficeViewModel`

Secondly, In server-side, You can get value `CityName` by joining between Office.CityId and City.

Hopefully, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) post is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

you should be add Collection of office in City Model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. I have class by name `OfficeViewModel`

```
public class OfficeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

}
```

then If we call the `Office` list `Offices` and the `City` list `Cities` You can do this with the following code

```
public IActionResult GetOffices(){

       List<OfficeViewModel> viewModel = Offices.Select(x => new OfficeViewModel
       {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            CityId = x.CityId,
            CityName = Cities.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CityId == x.CityId).CityName
        }).ToList();

        return View(viewModel);
}
```